# Is there any difference between war file created by maven package phase and war file created by maven war plugin war:war goal

Tags: java, maven, war

I would to know if a war file created using maven package phase would be equal to a war file created using maven war plugin war:war goal.

Assuming we have a pom.xml (extract) like this:

```
<groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
<artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

 ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <webappDirectory>/sample/servlet/container/deploy/directory</webappDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
```

I mean, it's necessary to have the plugin to build a war file (with no special restriction or feature). Please fee free to add any comment or suggestion. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

They are absolutelly equal. The purpose of `plugin` block with `maven-war-plugin` description is - for example - change default `webappDirectory` value. See more: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html